# Repeated service call - Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

what are options available to run the tasks in background on a regular intervals from mobile

I am using Xamarin forms and developing app for both iOS and Android.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[Xamarin Essentials issue re supporting background tasks](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/409).

Often recommended open source solution for background tasks in Xamarin is [shiny](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny).